# Every other letter in a list? LISP

Tags: list, lisp, letter

I am relatively new to LISP and am trying some new things for a Lisp program I am trying to create for a  presentation.

I need to be able to print every other character in a list, for example, (A B C D E F) would return (A C E) .. but I am getting easily confused...

I am normally program Java, so this comes kind of different to me.

I am trying to program this using purely recursion.. So something along the lines of....

```
(defun every-other (lst)
(cond ((null lst) 0)
((    **** now this is where I get confused as to what I should do..
I've tried adding a counter to only remove even numbered elements, but I think I implemented the counter wrong, I also tried remove(cadr lst) lst, but that would only return zeros...
```

any help would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you want it to be done recursively, just think it through case by case.

1. The list is null -> return the empty list [the empty list is '()].
2. Otherwise the list is not null -> In this case you want to build a new list containing
                                     the first element, skip the second element, then grab
                                     every-other element of the remaining list.

Turning this case analysis into code looks something like this:

```
(defun every-other (lst)
  (cond
    ;; If the list is null return the empty list. 
    ((null lst) '()) 
    ;; If the list is not null, construct [cons] a new list with the first element of lst
    ;; and every-other element of the list after the first two elements [rest returns the   
    ;; list without the first element, so we can just use it twice].
    (t (cons (first lst) (every-other (rest (rest lst)))))))
```

Now going through the evaluation of this code should look something like this:

```
(every-other '(a b c d e f))
=> (cons 'a (every-other '(c d e f)))
=> (cons 'a (cons 'c (every-other '(e f))))
=> (cons 'a (cons 'c (cons 'e (every-other '())))
=> (cons 'a (cons 'c (cons 'e '())))
=> (cons 'a (cons 'c '(e)))
=> (cons 'a '(c e))
=> '(a c e)
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun, a `loop`-based solution:

```
(defun every-other (lst)
  (loop 
    for i in lst
    for keep = t then (not keep) 
    if keep collect i))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a loop.

```
(loop :for c :in '(a b c d e f) :by #'cddr
      :collect c)
```

`:By` in a `for`-`in` clause sets the stepping function (default is `#'cdr`).  In order to get every other element, step two steps each time.  `Cddr` is a shortcut for applying `cdr` two times.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun aaa (x)
   (aa (length x) x))
(defun aa (n x)
        (cond ((null x) nil)
              ((evenp (- n (length x))) (cons (car x) (aa n (cdr x))))
              (t (aa n (cdr x)))))
```

This is a stupid case  lol~

Answer (score 0):

shorter recursive solution:

```
(defun every-other (l)
  (unless (null l)
    (cons (first l) (every-other (cddr l)))))
```